# Python logging format handler stdout default format

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I'm using `logging` standard library and add the handler to output to stdout. However, the new handler doesn't seem to have the default logging format, below is the example

```py
In [23]: root = logging.getLogger() 
    ...: handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout) 
    ...: log_level_int = getattr(logging, "INFO") 
    ...: root.setLevel(log_level_int) 
    ...: handler.setLevel(log_level_int) 
    ...: root.addHandler(handler)          

In [28]: logging.info("test")                                                                                                                                                                                      
INFO:root:test # default stderr handler
test # newly added stdout handler, doesn't have the log level information printed
```

How can the new stdout handler use the same format as the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a custom handler, you need to set the formatter.

```
In [32]: handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))


In [33]: logging.error('test')
root - ERROR - test
```

or even the default formatter:

```
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(logging.BASIC_FORMAT))
```

[Available logging attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes)

> How can the new stdout handler use the same format as the default?

You can also use the [logging.basicConfig](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) logging setup.

From the docs:

> Does basic configuration for the logging system by creating a
> StreamHandler with a default Formatter and adding it to the root
> logger.

So something as simple as:

```
import logging
import sys

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.INFO)
```

```
logging.info('test')
```

results in:

```
INFO:root:test
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks a lot!